# scala akka how to catch ActorInitializationException when using ask pattern

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I'm doing something like this:

```
...lots of surrounding context...
val actor = context.actorOf(Props(new Actor(...))
(actor ? message) onComplete {
  case Done => {
   println("done")
   Do stuff with the surrounding context of this actor 
  }
  case _ => {
   println("got wildcard") // try to handle error message here
  }
}
```

`Actor` is failing at initialization with

`akka.actor.ActorInitializationException` (in that actors context)

In the parent actor I am getting `**dead letters encountered.**` 
since `actor` was never created properly and `"message"` couldn't be delivered.

In this scenario the `"ask?"` pattern never returns properly.

I could create a `SupervisorStrategy` in the parent global level,  but I need to understand the context of the actor that generated the exception and it isn't possible (or convenient) handling it at the global level

Is there a way to "catch" the initialization exception in the `"ask"` context `actor ? message`?

Comment: There is `implicit` timeout associated with `ask` operation.  You could treat any timeout as failure of target actor and act accordingly in parent (where you at least know which target is failed).

Comment: indeed that is what is happening now. But the timeout is 120 minutes as the actor is very long running operation. It isn't a good option in this case :(

Comment: Then can you offload long running operation to a `Future` started by target actor and piped back to target once future completes? Then target could quickly respond to `isInited` message, `isLongRunningOpInProgress` and `getLongRunningOpResult` messages ...

Comment: it just requires more boiler code. I could create an intermedant proxy actor that will check if the SupervisorStrategy got ActorInitializationException and forward the message

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the extra boiler code

Answer (score -1):

According to akka philosophy `ask` should be used only when you interact with the actor from the outside of the actor system.
Since you have a reference to the `context` seems that you are inside the actor code. So you should try to get rid of `ask`.

If I'm wrong and you call `ask` from non-akka code then you shouldn't try to rely on anything that happens inside the actor system. All that you have is an `ActorRef` with no guaranties what is on the other side of this reference.

Comment: `ask` can be used from inside an actor as well, it allows you to easily understand context of reply to your `ask` (w/o it, you'll need to pass context handle in messages themselves, and it may be inconvenient). For example, see https://www.nurkiewicz.com/2014/01/three-flavours-of-request-response.html